# CSS gradient background on div

Tags: html, css

How do I get A similar style to the below active div? It seems that the color is kind of fading.

[image]

Comment: might help to at least post where you saw that so people can see the original code

Comment: It's from a photoshop design, I don't have the CSS. I just want the CSS to get the effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `linear-gradient` for that, as it is described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient). You can do the following:

```
.hoverable:hover {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(white, lightgray);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(white, lightgray);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(white, lightgray);
  background: linear-gradient(white, lightgray);
}
```

You can check a demo on [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0uebwcdv/)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```css
#grad1 {
    height: 200px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,0,0,0), rgba(255,0,0,1)); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255,0,0,0), rgba(255,0,0,1)); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255,0,0,0), rgba(255,0,0,1)); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(255,0,0,0), rgba(245,245,245,1)); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h3>Linear Gradient - Transparency</h3>

<div id="grad1"></div>

</body>
</html>
```